# did pyodide support selenium(webdriver for automate login)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

did pyodide support selenium(web driver for automate login)
I don't know whether pyodide supports the selenium library of Python or not
I was doing some automation like Facebook login automation with react js but I encounter an error.